# Extract file content with ManifoldCF

Tags: apache-tika, manifoldcf

I'm trying to use ManifoldCF with the File System Connector.

It works like a charm : with the Tika content extractor implemented, I got all the expected metadata from my documents.

But...
How to configure  ManifoldCF in order to get the equivalent of this command :
 java -jar tika-app-1.9.jar --text
I mean, I want to get the CONTENT of the file and pushed it in my Output Connections. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up the transformer in pipeline. Before you configure your output connector add [Tika transformer](https://manifoldcf.apache.org/release/trunk/en_US/end-user-documentation.html#tikaextractor) . With this setup you should be able get your meta data extracted based on your document type, eventually you should see that content and meta-data fed into your output connector (eg. solr)

Comment: Hello  kuhajeyan, thanks a lot for your help! I already set the transformer in the pipeline. My problem is in my result set : I got  the base 64 encoded version in my field file._content while I expected the content "ready to use"

Comment: @GoUeDaRd what are the type of tiles that you are trying to index

Comment: Microsoft office files and PDF

Comment: Hi GoUeDaRb, I have the same problem over here. Did you found any solution?